# Eval() only way i know, is there other?

Tags: php, internationalization

I have language files with translations of content in a website.
Each different language will load a different file.

Now I would like to have something like this, that I need to echo on the page and include in a email sent on `form` submit:

```
$lang["booking_mail_header"]='Dear '.$first_name.', thank you for your contact!';
```

The problems here is that `$lang[]` is loaded before `$first_name` is defined and `$first_name` is user inputed content, thus unsafe.

I thought about using `eval()` and then thought again and didn't. Is there another way?

The variable in this point of the script has already passed this regex check:
 `preg_match('/^[a-öA-Ö0-9-. ]*$/', $first_name)`

Comment: Instead of the array list, you could also investigate a gettext-style scheme. Apart from placeholders you could also use escaped variable specifiers `'Dear \$first_name ..'` and a `preg_replace_callback` later to replace and look them up (basically just more convoluted placeholders).

Comment: What could be unsafe, then?

Comment: @John, I read strong answers here about avoiding eval() when with user inputs. So due to my limited knowledge I did not. Maybe there is a safe way with `eval()` also?

Comment: Fair enough. Much better to be safe than sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just make it a template, e.g.

```
$lang["booking_mail_header"]='Dear %s, thank you for your contact!';
```

then use that with [sprintf](http://php.net/sprintf)

```
$msg=sprintf($lang["booking_mail_header"], $first_name);
```

You could also get cleverer, and use numbered arguments, which would allow your templates to reorder the inputs to sprintf, e.g.

```
  $lang["format_name"]='%2$s, %1$s';

  $msg=sprintf($lang["format_name"], $first_name, $last_name);
```

Once you've understood that, consider using [gettext](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.gettext.php), which uses the same basic idea, but wraps it up in some standard tools, which can aid keeping your translations maintained. Using that, you wouldn't keep you translations in an array, you'd just wrap your natural language in a _() wrapper, e.g.

```
$msg=sprintf(_('Dear %1$s, thank you for your contact!'), $first_name);
```

[gettext tools](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/gettext.html) can extract the natural language wrapped by the [_()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettext.php) function into a separate file for translation. A translator would use a standard tool like [poedit](http://www.poedit.net/) to produce these translations. At runtime, you select an appropriate translated version of this file, and `_()` will return that translation.

Comment: This is very interesting and will take me to some new reading. Just tried `sprintf()` and it worked great. Thank you Paul

Comment: I supose this is also a safer way instead of eval()